# python y loop de fechas

Tags: python, loops, datetime, array

buenas,
estoy intentando crear un vector que al ingresar una fecha de inicio y de termino, se generen fechas entremedio cada 6 meses y no logro hacerlo en python :(.
por ejemplo al darle el input 01-01-2010 y 01-01-2012 quiero que el vector contenga:

01-01-2010

01-07-2010

01-01-2011

01-07-2011

01-01-2012

el input lo estoy haciendo con datetime. pero no se que condición ponerle al For para completar un vector vació con estas fechas.

de antemano gracias por al ayuda.

saludos

Comment: En tu ejemplo muestras que la fecha inicial y final estan separadas en un multiplo de 6 meses, ¿Qué pasarìa si no fuese asi?

Comment: por ahora solo quiero resolver como hacer  que avance en múltiplos de 6 meses!.

Comment: MI pregunta no va por el intervalo sino por los extremos; por ejemplo si la entrada fuese: `01-01-2010 y 25-11-2012 `, ¿Qué es lo que deberias obtener?

Comment: en ese caso debería obtener adicionalmente a las fechas que ya puse, el 01-06-2012, ya que solo quiero obtener fechas cada 6 meses dentro del rango

Comment: Tus fechas no estan espaciadas cada 6 meses, sino de 5 y 7 meses

Comment: tienes toda la razòn. lo acabo de editar :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero que se debe hacer es crear la funcion add_months que añada meses, ya que date ni datetime manejan estas cantidades por ello usamos calendar. Despues creamos la funcion rangeMonth que itera hasta que la fecha nueva sea mayor que la fecha establecida como final

```
import datetime
import calendar

def add_months(sourcedate, months):
    month = sourcedate.month - 1 + months
    year = int(sourcedate.year + month / 12 )
    month = month % 12 + 1
    day = min(sourcedate.day,calendar.monthrange(year, month)[1])
    return datetime.date(year,month,day)


def rangeMonth(start, end, month):
    assert start <= end
    d = start
    dates = [d]
    while True:
        d =  add_months(d, 6)
        if d <= end:
            dates.append(d)
        else:
            break
    return dates

start = datetime.datetime.strptime('01-01-2010', "%d-%m-%Y").date()
end = datetime.datetime.strptime('01-01-2012', "%d-%m-%Y").date()

dates = rangeMonth(start, end, 6)

for date in dates:
    print(date.strftime("%d-%m-%Y"))
```

Output:

```
01-01-2010
01-07-2010
01-01-2011
01-07-2011
01-01-2012
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta. funciona perfecto. pero como puedo dejarlo como un vector para poder operar con el después?, lo que pasa es que luego debo calcular un vector que sea la diferencia de días entre esas fechas y otra cualquiera (19-11-2011 por ejemplo). me queda claro que al final tira a la pantalla el resultado, pero para tener un vector idéntico a lo que muestra la pantalla como lo hago?